# adding service to addthis 

Tags: addthis

I want to add my custom sharing service to an addthis widget.
According to the AddThis documentation the service must meet the specification of the oexchange format.
I've created everything and hosted it on my server. When trying to test it from the oexchange harness test, it fails.

There are two files generated from oexchnage

1. .well-known/host-meta
2. Target XRD File

I don't know about these two files. I generated them according the oexchange, but I'm still unable to test it with oexchange.

If anyone has been able to implement this, then please could you steer me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the the one solution for the .xrd file and i has been test it successfully with the oexchange test harness but still not able to test the .wellknown/ host-meta .